# coloring different parts of a series a different color

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

Hi I am quite new to highcharts but I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to change the color of different parts of a series.

For example here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/box-plot/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot',
            inverted: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
            title: {
                text: 'Experiment No.'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Observations'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 932,
                color: 'red',
                width: 1,
                label: {
                    text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [
                [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
                [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
                [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
                [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
                [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Outlier',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            type: 'scatter',
            data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
                [0, 644],
                [4, 718],
                [4, 951],
                [4, 969]
            ],
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

Does anyone know how to make the line in each series one color and the box in 
the series another color?

For example,
In the picture below I would like to know if it is possible to make each part of the series the color I highlighted it with.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options to control the colors on the boxplot. For example:

```
plotOptions: {
    boxplot: {
        color: 'red',
        whiskerColor: 'blue',
        stemColor: 'green',
        medianColor: 'yellow'
    }
}
```

As you can see both the box, median, whisker and stem can be colored separately.

See [this updated JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fcy7pm5d/).

See [the API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.boxplot) for a complete list of options for boxplot.